# jQuery script for clickNshow on a dokuwiki page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wiki, wikipedia, dokuwiki

I am making a dokuwiki for our company, but because the documents tend to get very large, I want to collapse the sections and only show the headers. The sections should appear when the header has been clicked.

The dokuwiki tips and tricks page shows a nice little jquery script that facilitates this [click and show behaviour](http://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:clicknshow). I modified it so that it only applies to 'h2' and none of the other headers.

Now the only thing I want is that the level 2 sections are by default hidden. I tried to add a CSS `div.level2{display:none;}` to the main page, but this does not really do the trick. It does hide the sections, but they do not appear anymore when the header is being clicked.

Is there a way to hide all sections below the h2 headers when the page loads using the javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("h2").click(function(){

jQuery("div.level2").toggle();

});
```

Try using this code.

The first line selects h2 and tell when its clicked it should call the function

the function toggles ur level 2 div

. . . . .

Comment: I edited toogle() to toggle(), but SOF say "you have to write 6 non-space characters": That's why I had to write the ". . . ." dots :(

Comment: could you please expand this example to show the context? Is this possible within the WYSYWIG editor, possibly using the 'html','code', or 'file' special tags?